# Work sheet's name is being renamed

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I used the below VBA code to copy 2 excel sheets within same workbook with other names that will be fetched from one sheet.

I have two sheets: Input and Output. These sheets will be copied with the name that is present in the cell C15 of Input sheet.

```
Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(15,3).Value
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("Input").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = Name & " " & "Input"
Sheets("Output").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = Name & " " & "Output"
```

This code is working fine until copying the Input sheet. But it is also renaming the Output sheet which causes an error at the last but one line because the sheet name Output is replaced with cell value of C15. Can anyone help me with this...

Comment: Avoid using "Name" as a variable name ! Being a property name, consider "Name" as a reserved word, to avoid problems.

Comment: What is the error?  Don't make us guess!

Comment: @iDevlop Cool!! That's Simple. Thank you so much

Comment: @RBarryYoung I've specified in detail in the question itself. Please refer to the edited question title

Comment: What @iDevlop mentioned is correct. You shouldn't use reserved names. However that is not the source of the error. In fact your code works for me just fine... there is one small typo error in your code `Sheets("Sheets.Count)` It should be `Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

Comment: @Pramod:  No you have not.  -1.

Comment: @RBarryYoung To clarify YOU There is no error. I've specified in the title as the sheet is being renamed. What is that you dont understand and what is there here to guess. I guess, you guess without reading the question

Comment: @Pramod: Look at your own question again. ***You*** said there was an error: "*But it is also renaming the Output sheet which causes an error ...*"

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's because the ActiveSheet isn't actually the sheet you want it to be. Since you know the sheet you want to rename is the last sheet, use the Sheets object instead.

```
newName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(15, 3).Value
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("Input").Select
Sheets("Input").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = newName & " " & "Input"
Sheets("Output").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = newName & " " & "Output"
```

Also as noted above, using Name as a variable isn't a good idea.

Comment: Thank you Nick. But the problem is with the keyword name only which is clarified by iDevelop. With your code, the result is same

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment above, try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sName As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        sName = .Sheets("Input").Cells(15, 3).Value

        .Sheets("Input").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = sName & " " & "Input"

        .Sheets("Output").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = sName & " " & "Output"
    End With
End Sub
```